# Не получается добавить ssl сертификат на сервер nginx

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, ssl

Всем привет, я новичок в разворачивании серверов (как и на stack**overflow**), неделю борюсь с проблемой и ничего не получается, что только не пробовал. У меня возникла проблема с установкой сертификата в nginx на ubuntu 18.04, `sudo nginx -t` ошибок не выдает. Вот мой файл с конфигурацией сайта:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /path/to/certificate.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/private.key;
    ssl_session_tickets off;
  
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    
    root /var/www/example.com/html;
    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
         allow all;
    }
}
```

Ещё изменял файл nginx.conf:

```
worker_processes auto;
...
events {
    worker_connections 768;
}

http {
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout 10m;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ....
}
```

В ufw открыл порт 443, когда вводишь команду `curl https://example.com`, то выдает следующее:
"curl(35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to example.com:443"

При вводе команды `nginx -V` пишет, что "TLS SNI support enabled"

Через telnet делал проверку открытых портов, и 443 порт там присутствует

Проверял еще с помощью данной команды `openssl s_client -connect example.com:443 -tls1 -tlsextdebug -status`, что сертификат поставился, но выводит следующее:

```
CONNECTED(00000005)
write:erno=104
---
no peer certificate available
---
no client certificate CA names sent
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 132 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation is NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol: TLSv1
    Cipher: 0000
    Session-ID: 
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key:
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: ..
    Timeout: 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
    Extended master secret: no
```

---

Если запускать с конфигурацией http, то всё работает. Вот только сертификат не получается поставить. Работает всё это в windows server 2019 с помощью virtualbox, в нем установлен ubuntu 18.04

Версия Nginx: 1.14.0, а OpenSSL: 1.1.1. Сертификат брал через sslforfree

Comment: Начнём с глупого вопроса: у вас домен `example.com` куплен, делегирован, связан с каким-нибудь DNS-сервером и его DNS-записи ведут в точности на ваш виртуалбокс?

Comment: Да, домен куплен и связан с DNS-сервером. Через http сайт работает нормально, а уже https не хочет

Comment: Что в логах nginx при его рестарте (а не reload'е)?

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev, ввел команду `systemctl status nginx` и вот, что он мне показывает после рестарта:
systemd[1]: Starting a high performance web server and reverse proxy server...
systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed to parse PID from file /run/nginx.pid: Invalid argument
systemd[1]: Starting a high performance web server and reverse proxy server.

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev, а если переделать конфиг под http, то выводит следующее: Stopped A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed to parse PID from file /run/nginx.pid: Invalid argument
systemd[1]: Started A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
 и всё хорошо работает

Comment: А всё же посмотрите пожалуйста в nginx'овы лог-файлы, больше всего, конечно, интересует errorlog. Вдруг там больше?

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev, к сожалению он просто пустой, есть только старые записи об ошибках, которые были несколько дней назад при настройке